# Switch color of sns.swarnplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, pandas-loc

Does anybody know, if its possible to switch the colors, so that i can distinguish every row instead of every column ? And how do I add in a legend, where i can see which player (one color for each player) has e.g. which pace?

My code is:

```
feldspieler = feldspieler["sofifa_id"]
skills = ['pace','shooting','passing','dribbling','defending','physic']

diagramm = plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))
plt.xticks(rotation=90,fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Skills', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Skill value', fontsize=30)
plt.title('Spielervergleich', fontsize = 40)

sns.set_palette("pastel")

for i in feldspieler: 
    i = fifa_21.loc[fifa_21['sofifa_id'] == i]
    i = pd.DataFrame(i, columns = skills)
    sns.swarmplot(data=i,size=12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `hue` parameter to the value of the column you're interested in (`sofifa_id`). You can then provide the whole dataset at once to plot the data. The legend will be added automatically.

So you should have a DataFrame with a `'skills'` column containing the different skills you have in x-axis here. If necessary, see the documentation for [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), in particular the third example.
Then, assuming the default column name `value` for the value after melting, call

```py
sns.swarmplot(data=fifa_21, x="skills", y="value", hue="sofifa_id")
```

This is from the official `swarmplot` function documentation ([here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)).

[image: Hue in swarmplot documentation]

Edit: So, seeing your data, you should really use `pd.melt` like this:
(I'm considering one row per player, with distinct `short_name` values).

```py
data = pd.melt(fifa_21, id_vars='short_name', var_name='skill', 
               value_vars=['pace', 'shooting', 'passing', 'dribbling', 
                           'defending', 'physic'])

sns.swarmplot(x='skill', y='value', hue='short_name', data=data)
```

`melt` will transform to columns and value from a `wide` format

| short_name | pace | shooting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_name | 85 | 92 |

to a `long` table format

| short_name | skill | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_name | pace | 85 |
| a_name | shooting | 92 |

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I have already looked at the documentation, but to use "hue", "X" and "y" must be determined. However, in my case I don't know what to put there.... I have tried various things, but error messages keep coming up.

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my answer. Please post a representative small part of the dataset if you're still unclear on how to do it from here (I may have misunderstood the structure of the data, but it would seem it is in `wide` format and should be made `long`).

Comment: i added an answer with a screenshot of my dataset. Thank you!

Comment: I updated again. Please also see my comment on your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Trevis.

Unfortunately, it still does not work.
Here you can find a screenshot of the dataset and the code that the graphic accesses.

```
while True:
    team = input("Welches Team suchen Sie?: ")
    
    if team in fifa_21.values:
        break
    else:
        print("Dieser Verein existiert nicht. Bitte achten Sie auf eine korrekte Schreibweise.")
            
                           
gesuchtes_team = fifa_21.loc[(fifa_21['club_name'] == team)]
spieler_verein = gesuchtes_team[["sofifa_id","short_name","nationality","age","player_positions","overall","value_eur"]]
spieler_verein = pd.DataFrame(spieler_verein)
spieler_verein = spieler_verein.reset_index(drop=True)
spieler_verein

feldspieler = spieler_verein.loc[spieler_verein.player_positions != "GK", :]
feldspieler = feldspieler.reset_index(drop=True)
feldspieler

feldspieler = feldspieler["sofifa_id"]
skills = ['pace','shooting','passing','dribbling','defending','physic']

diagramm = plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))
plt.xticks(rotation=90,fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Skills', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Skill value', fontsize=30)
plt.title('Spielervergleich', fontsize = 40)

sns.set_palette("pastel")

for i in feldspieler: 
    i = fifa_21.loc[fifa_21['sofifa_id'] == i]
    i = pd.DataFrame(i, columns = skills)
    sns.swarmplot(data=fifa_21, x="skills", y="skill_value", hue="sofifa_id")
    #sns.swarmplot(x =skills, y= pd.DataFrame(i, columns == skills) ,hue= "sofifa_id", data=i,size=12)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should instead edit your question to add information, and **really** preferably not as an image, then remove this answer.